# EmbeddedCassandra is not working with Cassandra Java driver 4.x

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandraunit

I was using cassandra-unit 3.5.0.1 with cassandra-driver-core 3.6.0.
My application was running fine.

Now when I try to upgrade to java-driver-core 4.3.1 and cassandra-unit 4.3.1.0, I am getting error when I try to run my tests in maven.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open hint directory
```

Below error is coming

```
"time="2022-06-17T07:13:30.945Z" level="ERROR" msg="[org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon:228][BatchlogTasks:1]
Exception in thread Thread[BatchlogTasks:1,5,main]java.lang.RuntimeException: \
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: \
    FSWriteError in C:\service\target\embeddedCassandra\hints"
```

Can some one help me out.

Comment: Saisree , welcome to stackoverflow.  Assuming this is for intergration tests. Is testcontainers something you have evaluated ? There is a cassandra testcontainer that makes IT very easy to work. Not directly an answer , something to consider

Answer (score 1):

`FSWriteError` is a low-level filesystem error originating from the Java file utilities library. In my experience, this is usually caused by permission issues on the parent directories.

Check that you have read/write permissions on the filesystem and try again. Cheers!